# How to reshape column matrix according to the row size of another matrix in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have one column matrix as follows

```
P = [1;2];
```

I Have another column matrix `Q` which has to be added to the first matrix. But the number of rows in second column matrix is always more than that of `P`

```
Q = [4;5;6];
```

i want to split or reshape `Q` according to size of `P` . if size of `P` is `n` , then first `n` elements of `Q` goes into the second column of output and the remaining elements to third coulmn while the first column of output is nothing but `P`

I need the output as below but I cannot use the reshape as I am not sure of the size of both matrices as they can vary.

```
output = [1 4 6;2 5 0];
```

Could someone assist me?

Thanks

Comment: why not? You just pad it with a zero when the size is odd and not pad it when size is even such that 2 columns can be made, and then just `reshape`.

Comment: If the sizes of the matrices can vary, you will have to make the size of matrix `Q` a multiple of the size of `P` by adding zeros at the end. Then you can safely reshape.

Comment: Are you sure that's the desired output?

Comment: @rayryeng yes i want to split or reshape `Q` according to size of `P` . if size of `P` is `n` , then first `n` elements of `Q` goes into the second column of `output` and the remaining elements to third coulmn while the first column of `output` is nothing but `P`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki yes that would work . i am thinking of a general formula for the number of zeros to add depending on the sizes of both inputs

Comment: @EyesOfÖzil Edit your post with that explanation. It wasn't clear at first read.

Comment: @rayryeng apologies for the confusion! Edited accordingly

Comment: @EyesOfÖzil That's great. Thank you. Good question btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Communications Toolbox, use [`vec2mat`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html):

```
result = vec2mat([P(:); Q(:)], numel(P)).';
```

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Thanks for the heads-up. Corrected now

Answer (score 2):

```
% first we fill Q with appropiate number of zeros 
% (basically we see how many times Q is bigger than P rounded up)   
new_Q = zeros(numel(P)*ceil(numel(Q)/numel(P)), 1);
new_Q(1:numel(Q)) = Q;

% then we create a new matrix containing `P` and the reshaped `new_Q`

R = [P reshape(new_Q, [numel(P), numel(new_Q)/numel(P)])]

R =

     1     4     6
     2     5     0
```

This will work for any size of `P` and `Q` if they are both initially vectors (not matrices)

Answer (score 1):

You can also append the required number of zeros within the `reshape` statement itself, resulting in a single line solution

```
R = [P reshape([Q; zeros(numel(P) - mod(numel(Q),numel(P)),1)],numel(P),[])]
```